# SQL Server query using Union - any good alternate possible?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, union

I have a SQL Server query as:

```
SELECT top 1 vConsentInfo  FROM 
(           
            SELECT cons.vConsentInfo,cons.dTimeStamp ,logs.iPartnerProfileID 
            FROM H_OutMessageLog logs INNER JOIN H_OutMessageConsent cons on cons.iOutMessageQID = logs.iOutQueueID 
                WHERE logs.iPatID = 65686 and logs.iPracID = 4
        UNION  
            SELECT cons.vConsentInfo,cons.dTimeStamp,Q.iPartnerProfileID 
            FROM H_OutMessageQueue Q INNER JOIN H_OutMessageConsent cons on cons.iOutMessageQID = Q.iOutQueueID 
                WHERE Q.iPatID = 65686 and Q.iPracID = 4
) A 
WHERE A.iPartnerProfileID = Prof.IPartnerProfileID
Order BY dTimeStamp DESC
```

The table works as : a record get inserted into `H_OutMessageQueue` at the begining; then its inserted into `H_OutMessageConsent`...
Now there is a seperate worker process that processes records from `H_OutMessageQueue` and log them into `H_OutMessageLog`....

Can I get rid of this `UNION` thing ? Please note that this is a sub Query of a larger `CTE` query.

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of the `UNION`?

Comment: I mean if there is some stronger construct for this purpose that i don't know....actually i had to make union so that i can sort and get the most recent entry within those two tables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, but it may not be *better*. You'll have to work this into your bigger query

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    cons.vConsentInfo,
    ISNULL(logs.iPartnerProfileID , Q.iPartnerProfileID) AS iPartnerProfileID
FROM 
    H_OutMessageConsent cons 
    LEFT JOIN
    H_OutMessageLog logs ON cons.iOutMessageQID = logs.iOutQueueID AND 
                               logs.iPatID = 65686 and logs.iPracID = 4
    LEFT JOIN
    H_OutMessageQueue Q ON cons.iOutMessageQID = Q.iOutQueueID  AND
                               Q.iPatID = 65686 and Q.iPracID = 4
WHERE
    ISNULL(logs.iPartnerProfileID , Q.iPartnerProfileID) IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY 
    cons.dTimeStamp DESC
```

Comment: seems good enough logical ... but does it perform better than Union or roughly same ???

Comment: @Umer: you'll have to try it in your environment

Answer (score 1):

**In addition to gbn reply. This will remove the extra burden from your query:).**

```
SELECT top 1 vConsentInfo  FROM 
(           
    SELECT cons.vConsentInfo,cons.dTimeStamp ,logs.iPartnerProfileID 
    From
    (
        Select iPartnerProfileID FROM H_OutMessageLog logs  
        WHERE logs.iPatID = 65686 and logs.iPracID = 4
    )logs
    Left JOIN H_OutMessageConsent cons on cons.iOutMessageQID = logs.iOutQueueID
    UNION  
    SELECT cons.vConsentInfo,cons.dTimeStamp,Q.iPartnerProfileID 
    From
    (
        Select iPartnerProfileID FROM H_OutMessageQueue Q 
        WHERE Q.iPatID = 65686 and Q.iPracID = 4
    )Q
    Left JOIN H_OutMessageConsent cons on cons.iOutMessageQID = Q.iOutQueueID 
) A 
WHERE A.iPartnerProfileID = Prof.IPartnerProfileID
Order BY dTimeStamp DESC
```

Comment: the inner most query, it selects only partner profileid...but it has a left join with H_OutMessageConsent on iOutQueueID to iOutMessageQID....i think you forgot to select iOutQueueID from Logs....however, got some idea...

Comment: This will be quite faster as join will be on filtered records...:)